# How to programmatically set the product attribute variation price in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a product attribute variation which has options of -
small - $20
medium - $25
large - $30

Since all the products in the store has the same price for this variations.

How to set the price for the attribute values programmatically?

3 attribute variation buttons are show on product page when I add them as variations.

How to change the price of product when "small" option is selected programmatically instead of setting price in variation options in admin panel.

Comment: Does you Gift-wrap checkbox comes from a plugin ? which one ?

Comment: It's not coming from plugin, it's an attribute we create for variations of a product.

Comment: If I understand : you created this attribute for variations only, and now you want to extend it to all products, even those without variations ? Can you show us how you created it ?

Answer (score 0):

As Per our understanding to want to add products with different sizes and different prices.

There is 2 way:

**1. You can add from woocommerece dashboard like this:**
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/woocommerce/product-variations/

2. You can add programmatically like this:

   ```
   function insert_product ($product_data)
   {
       $post = array( // Set up the basic post data to insert for our product

        'post_author'  => 1,
        'post_content' => $product_data['description'],
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_title'   => $product_data['name'],
        'post_parent'  => '',
        'post_type'    => 'product'
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post); // Insert the post returning the new post id

    if (!$post_id) // If there is no post id something has gone wrong so don't proceed
    {
        return false;
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $product_data['sku']); // Set its SKU
    update_post_meta( $post_id,'_visibility','visible'); // Set the product to visible, if not it won't show on the front end

    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $product_data['categories'], 'product_cat'); // Set up its categories
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type'); // Set it to a variable product type

     insert_product_attributes($post_id, $product_data['available_attributes'], $product_data['variations']); // Add attributes passing the new post id, attributes & variations
     insert_product_variations($post_id, $product_data['variations']); // Insert variations passing the new post id & variations
   }


    function insert_product_attributes ($post_id, $available_attributes, $variations)
   {
      foreach ($available_attributes as $attribute) // Go through each attribute
      {
        $values = array(); // Set up an array to store the current attributes values.

        foreach ($variations as $variation) // Loop each variation in the file
        {
            $attribute_keys = array_keys($variation['attributes']); // Get the keys for the current variations attributes

            foreach ($attribute_keys as $key) // Loop through each key
            {
                if ($key === $attribute) // If this attributes key is the top level attribute add the value to the $values array
                {
                    $values[] = $variation['attributes'][$key];
                }
            }
        }
        $values = array_unique($values); // Filter out duplicate values

        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $values, 'pa_' . $attribute);
    }

    $product_attributes_data = array(); // Setup array to hold our product attributes data

    foreach ($available_attributes as $attribute) // Loop round each attribute
    {
        $product_attributes_data['pa_'.$attribute] = array( // Set this attributes array to a key to using the prefix 'pa'

            'name'         => 'pa_'.$attribute,
            'value'        => '',
            'is_visible'   => '1',
            'is_variation' => '1',
            'is_taxonomy'  => '1'

        );
    }

    update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attributes_data); // Attach the above array to the new posts meta data key '_product_attributes'
   }

   function insert_product_variations ($post_id, $variations)
   {
     foreach ($variations as $index => $variation)
      {
        $variation_post = array( // Setup the post data for the variation

            'post_title'  => 'Variation #'.$index.' of '.count($variations).' for product#'. $post_id,
            'post_name'   => 'product-'.$post_id.'-variation-'.$index,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
            'guid'        => home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $post_id . '-variation-' . $index
        );

        $variation_post_id = wp_insert_post($variation_post); // Insert the variation

        foreach ($variation['attributes'] as $attribute => $value) // Loop through the variations attributes
        {
            $attribute_term = get_term_by('name', $value, 'pa_'.$attribute); // We need to insert the slug not the name into the variation post meta

            update_post_meta($variation_post_id, 'attribute_pa_'.$attribute, $attribute_term->slug);
        }

        update_post_meta($variation_post_id, '_price', $variation['price']);
        update_post_meta($variation_post_id, '_regular_price', $variation['price']);
       }
    }

    function insert_products ($products)
    {
       if (!empty($products)) // No point proceeding if there are no products
       {
          array_map('insert_product', $products); // Run 'insert_product' function from above for each product
       }
    }
    $json = file_get_contents('product-data.json'); // Get json from sample file
   // $products_data = json_decode($json_file, true); // Decode it into an array
   echo json_last_error();

   // if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
      //  $d = stripslashes($json);
    // }else{
     //  $d = $json;
    // }
    $d = json_decode($d,true);
    $products_data = json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $json), true );
    echo "<h1>json</h1>";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<h1>Product data</h1>";
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($products_data);
    echo "</pre>";

    insert_products($products_data);
   ```

**Where $product_data  sample:**

```
$product_data = array(
    'sku' => '123SKU',
    'categories' => array('size', 'color'),
    'available_attributes' => array('size', 'color'),
    'variations' => array( 
        'size' => array(
            'attributes' => array( 'XL', 'M', 'S' ), 
        ),
        'color' => array(
            'attributes' => array( 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green' )  
        )
    )
 )

 insert_products($products_data);
```

Note: You can create product-data.json and import product or you can create $product_data = (); and set on insert_products() function.

**For Aditional Info:**

You can also check this URL for more info https://newbedev.com/create-programmatically-a-woocommerce-product-variation-with-new-attribute-values

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was away from the computer. I just want to hardcode the price of the attribute value. Attribute is added from the wordpress backend. So if user selects small increase the price by $2 and $4 for medium and $6 for large. Since there are lots of variations changing the price of attribute is too tiring. Hence just programmatically fix the price for the small, medium and large.